# Creating select with optgroup using jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a select generated using jsp, which works just fine. Here is the code I use:

```
<select class="heading4Black" name="DailyTasks" onchange="showreport(this)">
<%
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    elem = (Element) links.get(i);
%>

    <option title='<%=elem.attributeValue("tooltip") %>' value='<%= elem.attributeValue("url")%>' <%= (i == 0) ? "selected" : "" %> ><%=elem.attributeValue("name")%></option>
<%
}
%>
    </select>
```

This gives me the output that I want. Now, I have a requirement to add an optgroup to one of the select options, so instead of having a select with options like this:

```
option1
option2
option3
```

I need to make option2 an html optgroup, such that my select should look like this:

```
option1
option2
    subopt1
    subopt2
option3
```

I've been trying to use jstl and c:choose, but I'm having much trouble with this. Here is the code I've tried using (and variations thereof):

```
<select class="heading4Black" name="DailyTasks" onchange=" somefunction(this)">
<%
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    elem = (Element) links.get(i);
 %>

<c:choose>
<c:when test="'${elem[i].attributeValue("name")}'=='Facility Ticket'">
 <optgroup label="Some String">
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
    </optgroup>      
</c:when>    
<c:otherwise>
    <option title='<%=elem.attributeValue("tooltip") %>' value='<%= elem.attributeValue("url")%>' <%= (i == 0) ? "selected" : "" %> ><%=elem.attributeValue("name")%></option>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>         
 <%
   }
  %>
 </select>
```

What I get instead is a select with options that look like this:

```
Some String
   subopt1
   subopt2
Option1
Some String
   subopt1
   subopt2
Option2
Some String
   subopt1
   subopt2
```

Can someone provide some guidance as to how to make this work? Please bear in mind that I'm really a javascript guy. I got tossed this jsp project because I had some exposure to it about 10 years ago.
Thanks

Comment: is my solution what you are looking for. If yes, you can accept and upvote the answer. If not, provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

Your output suggests that the JSTL (choose,when,otherwise) has been ignored.
You get the code inside the `when` **and** `otherwise` for each iteration.
This is because you probably forgot to add this line in front of the JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

By adding the above line, you activate the evaluation of the Core of the JSP Standard Tag Library. So tags like `<c:tags>` will be processed. Otherwise they are sent to the browser as they are.
(You can see the html code in the browser (Chrome&Firefox) by pressing `CTRL+U`)

**Issue 2:**

After fixing that, you will probably encounter compilation errors.
The `c:when` line is buggy:

```
<c:when test="'${elem[i].attributeValue("name")}'=='Facility Ticket'">
```

I can see multiple problems:

- No need of index `[i]`, you did already accessed the element by `links.get(i)`:
- You try to access `elem` through Expression Language `${elem...}`, but this work only if this scriptlet variable is assigned to an attribute.

**Solution with scriptlets:**

If you use scriptlets in the `c:when test`, it could look like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<select class="heading4Black" name="DailyTasks" onchange=" somefunction(this)">
<%
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    // added Element type in front
    Element elem = (Element) links.get(i);
 %>

<c:choose>
<c:when test="<%=elem.attributeValue("name").equals("Facility Ticket")%>">
 <optgroup label="Some String">
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
    </optgroup>      
</c:when>    
<c:otherwise>
    <option title='<%=elem.attributeValue("tooltip") %>' 
            value='<%= elem.attributeValue("url")%>' 
          <%= (i == 0) ? "selected" : "" %> 
    >
       <%=elem.attributeValue("name")%>
    </option>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>         
 <%
   }
  %>
 </select>
```

**Solution without scriptlets. Only with JSTL and JSP-EL:**

You are mixing scriptlets, EL and JSTL. It could be unified.

The `for` from the scriptlet, coulde be replaced by `<c:forEach>`.
And all JSP expression (`<%= ... %>`) could be replaced by EL (Expression Language).
But first, where the `links` are prepared, set them to request attribute like this:

```
request.setAttribute("links", links);
```

After that the JSP could be look like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<select class="heading4Black" name="DailyTasks" onchange=" somefunction(this)">
    <c:forEach var="elem" items="${links}" varStatus="varStatus">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${elem.attributeValue('name')=='Facility Ticket'}">
                <optgroup label="Some String">
                    <option>One</option>
                    <option>Two</option>
                </optgroup>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <option title="${elem.attributeValue('tooltip')}" 
                        value="${elem.attributeValue('url')}" 
                     <c:if test="${varStatus.index == 0}"> selected</c:if>
                >
                    ${elem.attributeValue('name')}
                </option>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Notice the usage of `varStatus.index` to access the iteration index.

Comment: I chose #1 as it was close to what I already had. The big problem, was the string comparison. The '==' is valid for javascript, but not in java as the string is an object, not a scalar. Just completely overlooked that issue. Thanks